# FIND_IN_SET with limit offset

Tags: mysql, sql

directly going for the code.

**users table**

```
+----+------------------+
| id | username         |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | becker.cornelius |
|  2 | claudine29       |
|  3 | dion37           |
|  4 | zkozey           |
|  5 | kasandra59       |
+----+------------------+
```

**lists table**

```
+----+---------------------------+
| id | name                      |
+----+---------------------------+
| 1 | List 1                     |
| 2 | List 2                     |
| 3 | List 3                     |
| 4 | List 4                     |
| 5 | List 5                     |
+----+---------------------------+
```

**lists_data table**

```
+-----+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id  | list_id | user_id                                                        |
+-----+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 421 |      4 | 1,2,3,503433,707152,603114,342531,414463,977165                |
+-----+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`data` colum my contain 1 million users. Following is my code

```
select users.id, email, mobilenumber, firstname, surname, created_at
from users
inner join lists_data on find_in_set(users.id,lists_data.user_id) > 0 where lists_data.list_id = 97
```

Above code is working, only problem is slow and I cannot use pagination,

I've tried many methods. none of them are working as expected.

BTW, I cannot normalize the lists_data table since it may contain millions of record per list.

Comment: Why do you have `CSV` column in junction table?

Comment: `CSV` column? where?

Comment: `user_id` in `lists_data` table (i. e. `1,2,3,503433,707152,603114,342531,414463,977165`)

Comment: users are in a particular list, just to showing there may be more records

Comment: Please read about: [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) and schema design. 1) It will be normalized 2) It will have better performance (index usage) 3) Easier to maintain

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong data structure for a relational databases.  Your `lists_data` table should have columns for `list_id` and `user_id` (singular).  The example row would be multiple rows:

```
 id    list_id   user_id 
  1        97          1
  2        97          2
  3        97          3
  4        97     503433
  . . .
```

This is called a junction table.  And, although larger, SQL finds it much simpler to work with such tables.

Comment: Yes this can do, But issue is, If a list has 1million users there would  be 1 million records in `lists_data` table,

Comment: Data inserting will be painfull, DB size

Comment: @Mifas . . . Databases are designed to handle lots of data and a million users is not at all unreasonable.  You should use data structures appropriate for the tools you are using . . . and that is a junction table.